# duplicate data on refresh ios

Tags: ios, objective-c

I've got my reload function reloading data properly, but I'm getting duplicate data.  I've tried nil-ing out the changelist in the below spots and had no luck.  Should I be nil-ing out the jsonObject?  Or am I just putting it in the wrong spot.

Thanks for any help.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];

UIRefreshControl *refresh = [[UIRefreshControl alloc] init];
refresh.attributedTitle = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:@"Pull to refresh"];
[refresh addTarget:self action:@selector(refreshmytable:)   forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
self.refreshControl = refresh;

NSURLSessionConfiguration *config =
[NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration];

_session = [NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration:config
                                         delegate:self
            //   delegate:nil
                                    delegateQueue:nil];

[self fetchFeed];



}

- (void)refreshmytable:(UIRefreshControl *)refreshControl{

[self fetchFeed]; //Added 12:12 9.16.14
refreshControl.attributedTitle = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:@"Updating"];
NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[formatter setDateFormat:@"MMM d, h:mm a"];
NSString *updated = [NSString stringWithFormat:@" Last Update: %@", [formatter     stringFromDate:[NSDate date]]];
refreshControl.attributedTitle = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:updated];
                                  [refreshControl endRefreshing];

[self.tableView reloadData]; //Added this 11:32 9.16.14

}





- (void)fetchFeed
{
 NSString *userEID = MAP_getUsername();
 //NSLog(userEID);

 NSString *requestString1 = [@"URL" stringByAppendingString:userEID];

 NSString *requestString2 = @"&status=pending";

 NSString *requestString = [requestString1 stringByAppendingString:requestString2];

 //NSLog(requestString);

 /*NSString *requestString = @"http://URL";
*/
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:requestString];
NSURLRequest *req = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

NSURLSessionDataTask *dataTask =
[self.session dataTaskWithRequest:req
                completionHandler:
 ^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {


     NSDictionary *jsonObject = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data
                                                                options:0
                                                                 error:nil];
     self.changeList = jsonObject[@"List"];
     //self.changeList=nil; //tried to add here to remove duplicate data

     NSLog(@"%@", self.changeList);

     //- add code here to populate BNRItemStore with the change order list.
     // - following code should be rewritten in fetchFeed that will load BNRItemStore.
     if (self.changeList.count>0) {
         for (int i = 0; i < self.changeList.count; i++) {
             NSDictionary *coItem = self.changeList[i];

             [[BNRItemStore sharedStore]
              addItemWithApproverEid:coItem[@"approverEid"]
              assignmentGroup:coItem[@"assignmentGroup"]
              changeOrder:coItem[@"changeOrder"]
              subcategory:coItem[@"subCatagory"]
              title:coItem[@"title"]


              ];
         }
     }
     //NSLog(@"sizeof(NSInteger) = %@", @(sizeof(NSInteger)));
     //- end comment

     dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        [self.tableView reloadData];
     });
     //self.changeList=nil; //trying to null out list for refresh non duplicate data


   //  NSString *json = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
   //  NSLog(@"%@", json);
 }];


[dataTask resume];
}
```

Added BNRITEM.h class

```
@class BNRItem;

@interface BNRItemStore : NSObject

@property (nonatomic, readonly) NSArray *allItems;

// Notice that this is a class method and prefixed with a + instead of a -
+ (instancetype)sharedStore;
- (BNRItem *)addItemWithApproverEid:(NSString *)aEid
                assignmentGroup:(NSString *)aGroup
                    changeOrder:(NSString *)changeOrder
                    subcategory:(NSString *)subcategory
                          title:(NSString *)title;
@end
```

added BNRitem.m class

```
interface BNRItemStore ()

@property (nonatomic) NSMutableArray *privateItems;

@end

@implementation BNRItemStore

+ (instancetype)sharedStore
{
static BNRItemStore *sharedStore;

// Do I need to create a sharedStore?
if (!sharedStore) {
    sharedStore = [[self alloc] initPrivate];
}

return sharedStore;
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the issue is in this code:

```
[[BNRItemStore sharedStore]
              addItemWithApproverEid:coItem[@"approverEid"]
              assignmentGroup:coItem[@"assignmentGroup"]
              changeOrder:coItem[@"changeOrder"]
              subcategory:coItem[@"subCatagory"]
              title:coItem[@"title"]
```

You keep adding data to BNRItemStore but you don't remove the old one, there in nothing to do with self.changeList.

You need some way to remove all data before you add the new one, so on the beginning of the method fetchFeed you can call something like this:

```
[[BNRItemStore sharedStore] removeAllData];
```

Note I don't know that class BNRItemStore so removeAllData method probably doesn't exists, maybe there is another method to delete all data or maybe you nnd to implement one.

// Extended

I cannot see all of the method in .m file so I don't know where the data are stored by I believe it's stored in privateItems variable, maybe there is some method to remove all object from that array but it's not declared as public.

You can add a method definitions after

```
+ (instancetype)sharedStore;
```

in BNRITEM.h:

```
-(void)removeAllData;
```

And in BNRITEM.h implement it like that:

```
-(void)removeAllData {
    [self.privateItems removeAllObjects];
}
```

And as I said before call `[[BNRItemStore sharedStore] removeAllData];` at the beginning of fetchFeed method.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply.  I added my bnritem class.  It should be an NSObject. The shared store looks like an instancetype. (sorry, this is another devs code and I'm trying to figure it all out.)

Comment: You nailed it.  Thanks so much!